# How to detect taps on UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view that looks like this:

[image]

When the user tries to enter information the keyboard covers the `UITextViews` I thought trying to detect a tap on the `UITextView` using a `UIGestureRecognizer` that I added to the `UITextView`, and then change the constraints according to the view which was tapped. 
When I tap it the app crashes.

This is the code I used to detect a tap on the `UITextViews` -

```
//in viewDidLoad
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.textYoutube, action: "handleTap")
self.textYoutube.addGestureRecognizer(tap)    

func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        println("[handleTap] Tap ended")
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Is there a better way of moving the `UITextViews`?

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: This is an X/Y question because Apple details using a scroll view and adjusting the insets for this common situation in "[Managing the Keybaord](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: Shoaib, Is there something similar in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the tap on the textfield; implement the textField's delegate method textFieldShouldBeginEditing:

Answer (score 0):

Use the notifications, they supply the keyboard frame, with the new keyboards the size may vary and the frame will allow moving the input field above it.

Register for these notifications and handle moving the view out of the way of the keyboard:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Get the keyboard frame from the userInfo:

```
CGRect keyboarddRect = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

Release the notification in dealloc"

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Alternately use the delegate methods:

```
textViewDidBeginEditing:
textViewDidEndEditing:
```

Comment: I want to move each TextView independently, not move the entire view up when the keyboard shows. is it possible?

Comment: Sure, the method depends on wether Autolayout is used.